# How to query a list of items of same column using Solr Query syntax?

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to leave out only 4 specific strings of the column 'lastSnapshotStream'

My usual Phrase Query Syntax using Solr (which is working) is :

```
(NOT lastSnapshotStream:"CM-NIS-22.5.5" AND NOT lastSnapshotStream:"CM-NIS-22.6" AND NOT lastSnapshotStream:"CM-NIS-22.7" AND NOT lastSnapshotStream:"CM-NIS-22.5")
```

This is really big. How to simplify like something below ???

```
(NOT lastSnapshotStream IN ("CM-NIS-22.5.5","CM-NIS-22.6","CM-NIS-22.7","CM-NIS-22.5"))
```

or

```
(lastSnapshotStream: NOT IN ("CM-NIS-22.5.5","CM-NIS-22.6","CM-NIS-22.7","CM-NIS-22.5"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `field:(val1 OR val2 OR val3)` syntax to achieve `IN`:

`*:* -lastSnapshotStream:("CM-NIS-22.5.5" OR "CM-NIS-22.6" OR "CM-NIS-22.7" OR "CM-NIS-22.5")`

(the `*:*` in front is not necessary if you're only using the `-field` term, as it should be prepended to your query if not there). It's important that `OR` is capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

If the default operator is OR (the default) then you could just put

```
NOT lastSnapShotStream:(CM-NIS-22.5.5 CM-NIS-22.6.6 CM-NIS-22.4.4)
```

Comment: where are the quotes and comma inside braces for the items?

Comment: The comma isn't needed. The default operator is OR so the query is equivalent to lastSnapShotStream:(CM-NIS-22.5.5 OR CM-NIS-22.6.6).

Comment: The quotes are not needed is my example as the field used is defined as StrField in the schema. I would usually use this type of field for ID strings as applying linguistic rules to them doesn't usually make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In case the answers above didn't work for anyone reading this, try adding the `+` operator, e.g. +(field:val1 OR field:val2 OR field:val3), this fixed it for me.